# Why does "true && () => {}" produce "Uncaught SyntaxError: Malformed arrow function parameter list"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logic, logical-operators

The following code, when executed,

```
true && () => {}
```

yields

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Malformed arrow function parameter list
```

Why ?

Edit: I know wrapping the function in parenthesis works, thanks everyone, but I'd like to understand why can't the parser figure out it's a function in the first place.

Comment: `true && (() => {})` should work

Comment: It has to do with the parser, but I'm not exactly sure how it gets parsed such that it fails.

Comment: Here's where the parsing error is reported in V8: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/4b9b23521e6fd42373ebbcb20ebe03bf445494f9/src/parsing/parser.cc#L2226-L2229

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason is due the first part `true || (a)` being parsed by itself and THEN the parser is trying to parse the rest `=> {}`, which causes the error.

Comment: At first it seemed surprising to me that the parser would parse an empty set of parens like that, but I guess an empty set of parens parses validly because it could be a function call.

Answer (score 1):

It's parsing `true && ()` as the parameter list.

Comment: why am i getting that error in this context: `const r2 = await () => !r1.canceled && fsp.readFile('./config.json', 'utf8')`? any idea?

Answer (score -1):

Because arrow functions has special parsing rules. See [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) at **Parsing order** paragraph.

Comment: Only if you want to return a value. There's no syntax issue with not including a `return`.

Comment: @ziggywiggy you were right, it wasn’t the body block, but it’s the parsing order as stated in the official documentation I already linked. Answer edited.

Comment: MDN is not "official documentation." In any case, this is now a link-only answer – you should include the main points in the answer itself.