# Typescript and arrow noop

Tags: typescript

Hi I have question that might be very simple.

I am basically writing type called `onClick`

```
let onClick: Function | undefined;

onClick = onClick || () => { };

onClick = onClick || function () { };
```

The third line works but the second one doesnt.

Typescript gives like compilation error.

[Here is a link to the typescript playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=5&ssc=38&pln=3&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBA9gdgwsAlgYwNYC4IDECuNliKwQA%20EeAJiAGaIwgUDcAUM7AiqhALzTxJpSZABQBKHgD4IAbwgBfFm36cefDoJJlqeAkRgQxM%20YyA)

Im not sure what the problem is? It looks like valid javascript to me.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why does "true && () => {}" produce "Uncaught SyntaxError: Malformed arrow function parameter list"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55456281/why-does-true-produce-uncaught-syntaxerror-malformed-arrow-funct)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the logical or operator (||) with an empty arrow function (()=>{}) cause a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42679078/why-does-the-logical-or-operator-with-an-empty-arrow-function-caus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work. You need to add parentheses to wrap your arrow function. It is related to how JavaScript (and therefore TypeScript) are parsed; an explanation of why it happens [can be found on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#precedence_of_arrow).

```js
let onClick: Function | undefined;

onClick = onClick || (() => { });

onClick = onClick || function () { };
```

Comment: Glad it helps @blessenm